# How restart loop after enum's execution?

Tags: python, loops

Have a problem with my loop. How loop can be restarted after picking one of the numbers (as input) in "pick" IntEnum?
Any ideas?

```
from enum import IntEnum

Menu = IntEnum('pick', 'SAEMP25N SAEMP27N SAGDP1 SAGDP9N \
SAGDP6N SAINC5N SAINC6N SAPCE2')


pick = int(input("""
Pick number:
1. SAEMP25N
2. SAEMP27N
3. SAGDP1
4. SAGDP9N 
5. SAGDP6N
6. SAINC5N 
7. SAINC6N
8. SAPCE2
"""
                 ))

while pick < 8:
    
    if pick == Menu.SAEMP25N:
        print('nice')
        continue
    
    if pick == Menu.SAEMP27N:
        print('nice')
        continue
              
    else:
        print('..')
```

Comment: You currently do not have a loop.  The answer from ps2576 gives you the general idea of what to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're asking for input once, you need to do it repeatedly inside the loop:

```
while True:
    
    pick = int(input(""" .... """))
    
    if pick == Menu.SAEMP25N:
        print('nice')
    if pick == Menu.SAEMP27N:
        print('nice')
    else:
        print('..')
    
    if pick == 8: 
        break
```